# Difference between Boolan(!x) and Boolean(x==0)?

Tags: javascript

Code-snippet 1:

```
if ( !x ) { /* do stuff */ }
```

Code-snippet 2:

```
if ( x == 0 ) { /* do stuff */ }
```

For what values of `x` do these two code-snippets differ?

I am asking because, although I read the chapter on `==` in the spec, I still find it hard to deal with situations like the above (where it is combined with ToBoolean coercion).

btw, I want to know this just for the sake of knowing it (I want to understand the language), so don't bother telling me about `===` or asking me what `x` is.

***Update:*** I corrected the fist snippet. I meant `!x`.

Comment: you probably meant if (x == true) or something along the lines, 0 equates to false.

Comment: do you mean between `if (!x)` and `if (x == 0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will give you `true` for the first and `false` for the second snippet:

- `NaN`
- `null`
- `undefined`

And these will give you `false` for the first and `true` for the second snippet:

- `[]`
- "0" and any other string that converts to 0 using `Number(x)` such as "00", "000", "+0", and "-0" (which I will now call "noughty strings")
- an array containing a single element that is `0`, `null`, `undefined` or an empty or noughty string.

For everything else you'll get the same result for both snippets, although there may be one or two more cases I haven't thought of.

Comment: +1 Yea, I think the crucial fact here is that in the second case `x` is coerced to a Number value, so it is important to understand which values coerce to the number 0. Oh, so confusing :|

Answer (score 5):

- `[] == 0` is true; `![]` is false
- `null == 0` is false; `!null` is true
- `NaN == 0` is false; `!NaN` is true
- `undefined == 0` is false; `!undefined` is true

`!x` will check whether `x` is "falsy".
`x == 0` will check whether `x` is "equivalent to" `0`.

Both of these terms are defined by the Javascript spec.

Comment: @elusive: Yes; that's what I meant.

Comment: @SLaks As if it couldn't get any more confusing. Could you explain why `[] == 0` is true? I thought `[]` is an object...

Comment: They are not 100% opposites! (or in other words !x is not 100% same as x==0). See my answer for details.

Comment: @SLaks (!x) and (x==0) are considerably different. Now that I get that, I ask myself why I was trying to compare them in the fist place. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's an interesting one with regard to a non-empty String that has only space characters:

```
!!"   ";         // true
"   " == true;   // false
```

This is because when you do a `==` comparison, and one of the values being compared is a number or a boolean, an attempt is made to convert the other value to a number.

The reason you get the different result is that a string with only space characters converts to the number `0` (or falsey), while a string with only spaces converted to boolean via `!!` is seen as a non-empty string, and therefore `true`.

So:

```
var x = "   ";

alert( !x );      // false
alert( x == 0 );  // true
```

---

**EDIT:**

Probably the key thing to remember is that when comparing a number or boolean to a non number type, `==` uses *toNumber* conversion if possible, while `!` uses *toBoolean* conversion. They're not always the same.

It is easy to see the result of the *toBoolean* conversion using `!!`. As in:

```
alert( !![] );   // true
```

But you can't really see the result of the *toNumber* conversion when using `==`.

You can, however, use the unary `+` to see the result of a *toNumber* conversion. As in:

```
alert( +[] );   // 0
```

I'm pretty sure that what happens in the case of an Array, is that it first gets a `toString` call. Therefore:

```
// ---------------------toString result-------toNumber result (from string) 
alert( +[] );       //       ""                   0    
alert( +[""] );     //       ""                   0    
alert( +["    "] ); //       "     "              0    
alert( +[0] );      //       "0"                  0    
alert( +["0"] );    //       "0"                  0    
alert( +["3"] );    //       "3"                  3    
alert( +[3,4] );    //       "3,4"               NaN
```

Comment: +1 Dear God, type coercion combined with `==` is by far the most confusing part of JavaScript.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - Indeed it is. Better to use `===` if there's any doubt. This specific situation was asked about the other day. I had to read through the spec a bit to find out why this was. Sure enough, I found that when it converts a String to a Number, an empty string and a string with only spaces is considered to be `0`.

Comment: **ECMAScript 5, Section 9.3.1**: *A StringNumericLiteral that is empty or contains only white space is converted to +0.* **ECMAScript 5, Section 9.2**: *String: The result is false if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero); otherwise the result is true.* So with regard to a non-empty string with only spaces, the result of the two for purposes of comparison of their `true/false` value is opposite.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: the two are almost always the same but not 100% the same.**

**An example would be `(!'0')` which is false whereas `('0' == 0)` is true**

**Details:**

From: http://www.joeyjavas.com/2007/08/04/javascript-true-false-checking-for-boolean-values/

> Checking if a value is true or false is simple in JavaScript. All values evaluate to true, except for:

```
0
-0
null
undefined
NaN
empty string
false
```

Therefore, `(!x)` will be true for all of the above values of `x` and only those.

As for (x == 0), it will be true for any value of x which - [when converted according to "==" conversion rules](http://www.webreference.com/js/column26/equality.html) - is converted to 0 when compared to a number (for example, Boolean `false` value). Other examples that compare true to `==0` are objects which generate 0 from their `valueOf()` methods, or a string `'0'`, or an empty Array (`[]`)

Comment: +1 Yea, (x == 0) will coerce x to a numeric value. I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two is that

```
if ( x ) { ... }
```

Tests whether x is "truthy"

Whereas

```
if ( x == 0 ) { ... }
```

Does type coercion between x and 0.

I presume you mean something like

```
if (x == 0) vs if (!x)
```

The main difference is type coercion of x to a number vs checking if x is falsy.

Clearly `NaN` itself will never equal 0 since its not a number. `undefined` will also coerce to NaN so that is not caught by `== 0` I can't give a good explanation why `null` is not caught by `0` since `Number(null) == 0`

Comment: Sorry, I got a typo in my question. I meant `!x` not `x`

Comment: For a laugh, do an: alert(typeof NaN);

Answer (score 0):

The first test will succeed when `x` is non-zero, or evaluates to an object (as opposed to `null` or `undefined`), or is a non-empty string.  So if `x` is 0 then the condition fails, but if it is "0" then it succeeds.

The second test will succeed when `x` is convertible to 0.  This means it must not be null, undefined, or an object to pass this test.  And it may be "0" or "".

In other words, these conditionals **are not opposites**.  The value "0" will pass both tests, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Code Snippet 1 will execute if `x` is "falsy" value. In Javascript, this means 0, -0, null, undefined, NaN, "", or false. Code Snippet 2, however, will only execute if `x` is zero. Unlike the first condition, this does not include other "falsy" values.

Comment: The second snippet will execute not only if `x` is 0, but for all values that coerce to 0. Like "0" or []

Comment: I was aware that `"0"` would coerce to `0`, but was not aware that so many other values did as well. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 0):

After some lookups, have to change my awnser.
There's no simple logic, implicit equality operations follows an algorithm.
http://interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-11.html#a-11.9.3

I can't sum it up better then what the algoritm describes, it would just get more confusing.

So it's `(!x)` is equivalent to `(typeof x === false)` aka (not true)
And `(x == 0)` gets compared by algorithm.

Comment: In your examples at the bottom, the third one is incorrect. Because there's no boolean or number conversions happening, it is comparing the two Array object instances to see if they are the same instance. This returns `false` because they are two unique instances.

Comment: @patrick, thanks, it does a 2 way conversion and comparison afterall ;) updated

Comment: You're welcome. The conversions are tricky. When comparing an Object to a number, as far as I can tell, the Object is sent to *ToPrimitive* which asks for *DefaultValue* which calls *valueOf* which will return an object, so it proceeds to call *toString* returning that value. Then it compares the result of *String* == *Number* which means that the String gets converted with *toNumber*. So ultimately, it is `Array > ToString > ToNumber === Number`. Glad I don't have to read the spec every day! :o)

Comment: @patrick yeh, and I was wrong still, the algorithm described in the spec is the best bet for clarity.

Comment: It really makes me wonder how it's possible that half way through writing that algorithm it didn't occur to them that this whole implicit type coercion concept is perhaps not the best idea.