# JavaScript type casting

Tags: javascript, types, casting

Consider empty JavaScript array:

```
var a = [];
alert(a == false); // shows true
alert(!a); // shows false!
```

How to explain this?
What are the rules?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do alert(!!"0") and alert(false == "0") both output true in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567393/why-do-alert0-and-alertfalse-0-both-output-true-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for pointing. But not exactly, I ask for generic rules.

Comment: When it comes to the loose `==` operator, the rules aren't so generic. You should read through the Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm referenced by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626361/javascript-type-casting/4626420#4626420).

Comment: Or, if you want to keep things simple, just avoid type coercion altogether. There may be some good use cases for coercion (`==`), but as a general rule, you can just avoid it (`===`). And then, you can build on that rule, and add exceptions where you do want to coerce.

Comment: **see also:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318654

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/966449:

**`a == false`:**

In this case, the type of the left-hand side is object, the type of the right-hand side is boolean. Javascript first converts the boolean to a number, yielding `0`. Then it converts the object to a "primitive", yielding the empty string. Next it compares the empty string to `0`. The empty string is converted to a number, yielding `0`, which is numerically equal to the `0` on the right-hand side, so the result of the entire expression is `true`.

See §11.9.3 of the [ECMAScript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) for all the gory details.

**`(!a)`:**

In this case Javascript converts the object to the boolean true, then inverts it, resulting in false.

Comment: here's a direct link to the afore-mentioned ECMA spec: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Answer (score 8):

The `!` operator checks whether its operand is "falsy".

The following are true:

- `!false`
- `!0`
- `!null`
- `!NaN`
- `!undefined`
- `!""`

---

The `==` operator checks for loose equality, which has nothing to do with falsiness.

Specifically, `a == b` will convert to operands to numbers, then compare the numbers.
Strings containing numbers convert to the numbers that they contain; booleans convert to `0` and `1`.
Objects are converted by calling `valueOf`, if defined.

Thus, all of the following are true:

- `"1" == 1`
- `"0" == false`
- `"1" == true`
- `"2" != true`
- `"2" != false`
- `({ valueOf:function() { return 2; } }) == 2`
- `({ valueOf:function() { return 1; } }) == true`

Comment: How are ("2" != true),  ("2" != false) both true?

Comment: @qwerty: The same way that `2 != 3` and `2 != 4` are both true

Comment: Oh because false == Number(0), true == Number(1) . Got it thanks

Answer (score 5):

The `==` operator when one of the operands if Boolean, type-converts the other to Number.

```
[] == 0;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
0 == 0;
```

You can see the complete details of [The Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-11.9.3) on the specification.

As you can see, an empty array object, when converted to Number, produces `0`:

```
+[]; // 0
Number(0);
```

This is really because its toString method produces an empty string, for example:

```
[].toString(); // ""

+""; // 0
Number(""); // 0
```

Answer (score 1):

When comparing an object to a primitive value via the `==` operator, the object coerces into an primitive value itself (number or string). In this case `[]` coerces into `0`, then `false` coerces into `0`:

```
[] == false
0 == false
0 == 0
```

which is true.

The `!` operator coerces into boolean and then inverts the value. `[]` into boolean is `true` (like with any object). Then invert to become `false`

```
![]
!true
false
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers the question, but there is a new library for getting around all of Javascript's Typecasting weirdnesses:

[Typecast.js](http://www.typecastjs.org/)

*In a sentence, Typecast solves all the simple problems, so you can focus on the big ones. Typecast fixes what's wrong with Javascript by creating a complete platform for strongly-typed variables in Javascript.*