# Falsy Values in Javascript with Coersion

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain to me why ... (this is in the chrome console)

null == false //false

!null == false //false

[] ? 'hello' : 'goodbye' //'hello'

[] == true ? 'hello' : 'goodbye' //'goodbye'

I could come up with a bunch more, but basically how does javascript arrive at these results?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript type casting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4626361/javascript-type-casting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript does a lot of type casting which is not apparent without knowing it ([JavaScript equality transitivity is weird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5447153/javascript-equality-transitivity-is-weird?lq=1)).

The `!` NOT operator, the `Boolean` function, the `? :` ternary operator, `if`-clauses and the logical AND/OR operators do use the internal [`ToBoolean` conversion](http://es5.github.io/#x9.2) - it is what is producing our understanding of the *falsy* value `0`, `NaN`, `""`, `null`, `undefined` and `false`.

However, when you are comparing things the [(non-strict) equality comparsion algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x11.9.3) comes into play, which produces some seemingly odd results when comparing diagonal types with each other. In your case:

- `null` is only equal to itself or `undefined` but not to `false`
- When you are comparing an array object to a boolean, it is getting more complicated. Booleans get compared to other types as if they were numbers, i.e. `true` is casted to `1` first. Then, when an object is compared to a number, it will be casted [to a primitive value](http://es5.github.io/#x9.1) (without a preferred type) - invoking the [`DefaultValue` algorithm](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.8) which essentially is calling the [arrays' `.toString` method](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.2) which will [`.join()` it](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.5). So `[]` is casted to `""` - which then is passed to [`ToNumber`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.3.1) since it will be compared against `1`. In the end `0` *is not* `1`. However, `[] == false` and `[1] == true` or `["1"] == true` hold…

Answer (score 0):

*magic* *waves hands mysteriously*

On a more serious note, for the first two, the `!` operator calls `toBoolean` on `null`, so if you checked `!null == !false`  or `!!null == false` you should get `true`. Similar things are likely happening in the other cases.

With information provided by Tore Hanssen, we can answer the other two as well.  [] is a 'truthy' value, but not a boolean, so directly comparing it to true returns `false`.  However, you could use the ! operator again to make it a boolean, so `!![] == true` returns `true`!

Comment: with the other cases, an empty array is not undefined or null, so it returns true, but it is not a boolean == true, so thats why it says goodbye

Comment: @ToreHanssen Ah, so it is something similar then :) Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting post on this topic here: http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/

In some of your examples, to force coercion, just using "==" is not enough.

!!null == false

!![]

!![] == true