# Could anyone explain x == !x is True?

Tags: javascript

I have no idea about this crazy code.

```
const x = [0];
x == x // True. I understand this
x == !x // True ???
```

I cannot understand what happen inside javascript and I need someone explain me this case.

Comment: This is under-researched.  Why is it upvoted?  If you did research, you should include all of the stackoverflow pages that were related but that failed to explain things sufficiently for you.

Comment: Type coercion bro, [0]==![0] gets converted to 0 == false, and then false == false, which is true.

Comment: Yes. I understand about == and === in javascript. But My question is about == operator only. What actually happen with this example? Since this creates bugs in many cases @mickmackusa

Comment: It only creates bugs when a programmer is using `==`. Easy fix: never, ever, use `==`, there's no reason to.

Comment: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/js-type-coercion-explained-27ba3d9a2839 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/19915688/2943403 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/4626361/2943403

Comment: @DanyalImran I think your answer is right. I tried to create another variable `a = [2]` and `a == !a` return FALSE.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thank you so much. I got the key work `type coercion` for this.