# Why is 0 == "" true in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Why is `0 == ""` true in JavaScript? I have found a [similar post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567393/why-do-alert0-and-alertfalse-0-both-output-true-in-javascript), but why is a number 0 similar an empty string? Of course, `0 === ""` is false.

Comment: You mean  0 is "casted" in false, "" is casted in false and the check is false == false => true

Comment: For PHP, see http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Comment: I believe it's because Javascript automagically coerces strings and numbers in some contexts, the == operator is one of those contexts, and "" coerces to 0.

Comment: @HorstWalter No. The sting is coerced to the Number type. See my answer.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: That comment with all the up votes is remarkably different from your answer (which is much better).

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ Well that was my first reaction. `:)`

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Ah, so you were thinking logically. Don't forget we're talking about JavaScript here. ;)

Comment: @Ӫ_._Ӫ Yea, I had the idea that a `==` comparison of two falsy values always evaluates to true. But then I remembered `NaN != NaN`... and that whole idea collapsed lol.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: Yep, `NaN` is the one value that will never pass a `==` test (or it will *always* pass a `!=` test).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
0 == ''
```

The left operand is of the type Number.
The right operand is of the type String.

In this case, the right operand is coerced to the type Number:

```
0 == Number('')
```

which results in

```
0 == 0
```

---

From the **Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm** (number 4):

> If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of
>   the comparison x == ToNumber(y).

Source: http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3

Comment: Thanks, I did just expect it the other way round, the 0 converted to string and then false.

Comment: Yes, on the other hand this means that saying both are falsy - as in the other answers, is not quite correct. Because - as you very well showed - the reason is that "" => 0. Thanks for your support!

Comment: @Horst - yes, that's right. Both _are_ falsy, as you can see if you use them alone in `if (0)` or `if("")`, but in the case of an `==` comparison that's not what's happening. (Not sure why Šime also left a comment above saying "Because both value are falsy".)

Comment: Ooh, I didn't know about es5.github.com. Much handier than typing out page numbers into the PDF.

Comment: @nnnnnn That was my first reaction. It turned out to be incorrect.

Comment: Which sometimes makes me hate Javascript's conversion system. In a language like R, it is 0 which would be converted to character "0" and the result would be, as expected, false.
Converting 0 to "0" does have some logic, but converting "" to 0 doesn't have any logic at all...