# In Javascript, how to explain 0 == "" returning true?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is 0 == “” true in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7605011/why-is-0-true-in-javascript)

The following is done in Firebug:

```
>>> 0 == ""
true

>>> "" == false
true
```

But how did the `""` get converted to `0`?  I think the reason they both returned `true` was that `""` gets converted to `0`, and in the first case, it becames `0 == 0`, and in the second case, first to `"" == 0` and then `0 == 0` and so both cases returned true, but how did `""` get converted into `0`?   The Javascript Definitive Guide says the string is converted to a number, but how specifically?

Comment: They're both "falsy" values. `0` is evaluated as `false` and so is the empty string: `""`.

Comment: Both `""` and `0` are `falsy` values. What you're looking for is the **strict equaliance** operator `===`, which of course return `false`.

Comment: Javascript doesn't work like that -- both `2` and `true` are "truthy" but `2 == true` will return `false` (but `1 == true` will return `true` so that can make you go crazy)

Comment: http://es5.github.com/#x11.9.3

Comment: And http://es5.github.com/#x9.3

Comment: The important thing in the specs is: `The MV of StringNumericLiteral ::: [empty] is 0`.