# Why "undefined" == undefined isn't true?

Tags: javascript, undefined, equality

The `==` operator is really funny. It is [usually doesn't behave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567393/why-do-alert0-and-alertfalse-0-both-output-true-in-javascript) as one think it will.

This led me to investigate exactly what is happening below the tip of the iceberg, and according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) it is as follow:

> If the two operands are not of the same type, JavaScript converts the
>   operands then applies strict comparison. If either operand is a number
>   or a boolean, the operands are converted to numbers if possible; else
>   if either operand is a string, the other operand is converted to a
>   string if possible. If both operands are objects, then JavaScript
>   compares internal references which are equal when operands refer to
>   the same object in memory.

<sub>[(source)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)</sub>

So, why doesn't `"undefined" == undefined` evaluate to true?

Shouldn't `undefined` be converted to `"undefined"` and then return true according to this description?

Comment: The key words in there are "**if possible**"

Comment: @Pointy but it is very possible `typeof ("" + undefined)`

Comment: I guess the conversion is `undefined => ""` and the comparison then is `"undefined" vs. ""`

Comment: Obligatory: https://twitter.com/#!/lassekorsgaard/status/201772655223902210

Comment: The conversion rules for `+` and for `==` are different.  Read starting at page 80 in the 5.1 spec.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`"undefined"` has a value. It is the 9 letters: u-n-d-e-f-i-n-e-d. Therefore, the string "undefined" does *not* have an undefined value. A `String` in javascript *can* have an undefined value, but here the `String` object has a defined value that just happens to spell "undefined".

Using the explanation you've provided, the `undefined` value on the right side would be converted to a `String` object with no value assigned, and then compared to the `String` "undefined", failing the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

For these kinds of questions, it's worth going back to the source: the [ECMAScript 5.1 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf). Section 11.9.3 has the complete description of what happens with double-equals:

1. If Type(x) is the same as Type(y), then 
   // some rules
2. If x is null and y is undefined, return true.
3. If x is undefined and y is null, return true.
4. If Type(x) is Number and Type(y) is String, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
5. If Type(x) is String and Type(y) is Number, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
6. If Type(x) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison ToNumber(x) == y.
7. If Type(y) is Boolean, return the result of the comparison x == ToNumber(y).
8. If Type(x) is either String or Number and Type(y) is Object, return the result of the comparison x == ToPrimitive(y).
9. If Type(x) is Object and Type(y) is either String or Number, return the result of the comparison ToPrimitive(x) == y.
10. Return false.

Since in this case Type(x) is `string` and Type(y) is `undefined`, the rules state that the result should be false.

Answer (score 0):

`undefined` is a primitive built in value in javascript of built in type `Undefined`. And doing a comparison such as `x == undefined`, has a special meaning in javascript: It checks whether a variable is not defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

`"undefined"` is literally a `string` and `undefined` is an `object`. I think it casts right side operand with `nothing` or `""` or `an empty string`. So `"undefined" == null` return `false`.

Comment: `undefined` is not an object. It's of type Undefined, not of type Object.

Answer (score -2):

`undefined` is a special javascript keyword, the following are ways to check for undefined variables/properties.

```
var a = undefined;

//if( a == undefined ) 

//if( a === undefined )
```