# Why javascript's alert shows strange values with arrays and objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, expression, alert

I have a difficulty of understanding why alert shows me a strange things in the following expression.

```
alert(!+{}[0]); //it shows "true"
```

Why "true" but not "undefined"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do alert(!!"0") and alert(false == "0") both output true in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567393/why-do-alert0-and-alertfalse-0-both-output-true-in-javascript)

Comment: because it's somewat in js: https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/wat

Comment: What do you think the output _should_ be?

Comment: I thought SyntaxError

Comment: *"I thought SyntaxError"* In your question you say you expect `undefined`?

Comment: It was one of options)

Answer (score 2):

> Why "true" but not "undefined"?

Because `!` is a boolean operator which always returns a boolean value. It would never produce the value `undefined`.

```
!false     // true
!''        // true
!null      // true
!undefined // true
!NaN       // true
!0         // true
```

---

Related: [What is the explanation for these bizarre JavaScript behaviours mentioned in the 'Wat' talk for CodeMash 2012?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9032856/218196)

Comment: So, it's convert all my expression into boolean after "+" sign?

Comment: No. `!` takes *any* value and converts it to a boolean. The `+` converts any value to a *number*.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the [NOT operator `!` will always return a boolean value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT), so if you were to examine your statements, you could break them down as follows :

```
{}[0]        // yields undefined
+(undefined) // assumes arithemetic, but doesn't know how to handle it so NaN
!(NaN)       // Since a boolean must be returned and something is there, return true
```

Answer (score 0):

Going step by step:

```
{}[0] == undefined
+undefined == NaN
!NaN == true
```

Answer (score 0):

The conversion is executed this way:

1. `!+{}[0]` (`{}[0]` -> `undefined`)
2. `!+undefined` ( `+undefined` -> `NaN` )
3. `!NaN` (`NaN` is falsy -> `false`)
4. `!false`
5. `true`

Logical not `!` always transforms the argument to a boolean primitive type.
Check more about the [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) and [logical not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_NOT_(!)).